# Kendo grid hierarchy data not displaying

Tags: javascript, mvvm, typescript, kendo-grid

I have an MVVM application using Kendo Grid, and I want to display hierarchy (nested grid). I am trying to replicate [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/machun/q2x9sn6w/1/) but I am not able to display the hierarchy data. How can I get the hierarchy records to display?

**cshtml code:**

```
<div id="custOrderGrid"
        data-role="grid"
        data-resizable="false"
        data-navigatable="true"
        data-editable="true"
        data-pageable="false"
        data-scrollable="true"
        onscroll="true"
        data-detail-template="child-template"
        data-columns="[
                { 'field': 'OrderID', 'title': '<b>Order #', 'width': 65 },
                { 'field': 'LineNo', 'title': '<b>Line Number', 'width': 65 },
                { 'field': 'ItemNo', 'title': '<b>Item Number', 'width': 65 },
                { 'field': 'Desc', 'title': '<b>Description', 'width': 150 }
            ]"
        data-bind="source: orderSearchResults"
        style="height: 55%">
</div>

<script id="child-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <div data-role="grid"
         data-bind="source: obj2"
         data-columns="[
    { field: 'name' },
    { field: 'oid' }
    ]"></div>
</script>
```

**typescript code:**

```
orderSearchResults = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  schema: {
    model: {
      id: "OrderID",
      fields: {
        LineNo: { type: "string" },
        ItemNo: { type: "string" },
        Description: { type: "string" }
      }
    }
  },
  data: [
    {
      OrderID: "L44ZX4", 
      LineNo: "15", 
      ItemNo: "*X1WCJH", 
      Description: "CDF9X2XSB",
      obj2: [
        {
          name: 'a1',
          oid: 1
        },
        {
          name: 'b1',
          oid: 2
        },
        {
          name: 'c1',
          oid: 3
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
});
```

The yellow highlighted section is where the Hierarchy data should be displayed.

[image]

Comment: are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [link](http://jsfiddle.net/b21zqeog/2/) to what I've tried.

I thought the hierarchy grid wasn't created but actually, it is created nested within the main grid.  Your screenshot doesn't display the right part of the grid, but you probably have 2 scroll arrows on the right side of the grid that would allow you to see the sub grid content.

Removing the `style="height: 55%"` fixed the problem.

N.B. I'm not sure if I reproduced you problem correctly...  in your screen shoot you do have another main record displayed so the subgrid would normally be displayed between those 2 main records.  If the height style was the reel problem, then the second main record would also be hidden.  If I'm wrong, feel free to update my example to reproduce your issue.